# How to adjust php results (placing comma) with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

In an ordering procedure a mail is sent out to the customer with an overview of the order details including the order total before all the details are stored into the database.

However the ordertotal is not separated with the necessary comma. I am trying to solve this with jQuery to add this comma prior to sending out the mail.

Used script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prijzen_weergeven($prijs){
if($prijs == 0){
    $prijs = '0,00';
    } else {
        $prijs_voor = substr($prijs, 0, -2);
        if(!$prijs_voor){
        $prijs_voor = 0;
        }
        $prijs_achter = substr($prijs, -2);
        $prijs = $prijs_voor.','.$prijs_achter;
        }
        return $prijs;  
        }
</script>
```

The corresponding line in the mail is:

```
<span style="color:#505050; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:none;">&euro;'.secure($_SESSION['bestelling']['aantal'] * prijs_stof($_SESSION['bestelling']['soort_stof'])).' </span><br />
```

How to combine the jQuery-function with the PHP code???? Thanks

Comment: You should always use english name notation to make code more readable for non dutch folk. Now, what is your issue? What result you get? What result you expect? What is the PHP code? Etc...

Comment: what are you trying to combine ? , separate php variables from js ones so that we know what needs to be combined,. By the looks of the inline css it should be <?php echo secure($_SESSION['bestelling']['aantal'] * prijs_stof($_SESSION['bestelling']['soort_stof'])) ?>  but I am not sure if you are mixing js function with php one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format your money using javascript. since you get it using php why don't you format it on the php side with [money_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) ?

```
money_format("%.2n",secure($_SESSION['bestelling']['aantal'] * prijs_stof($_SESSION['bestelling']['soort_stof'])))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your hint helped to solve the problem. However i added '/100' at the end of the string. This to make the correct reproduction of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using javascript for stuff you can do in PHP? If you just make another variable for the mail price it would solve the problem. So for example:

```
$_SESSION['price'] = 1095; //cents
$_SESSION['mail_price'] = $_SESSION['price']/100;
```

Then just printout the 'mail_price' in the mail, so you wont have to use javascript for that.

Oh and please use English name notation. I am also dutch so I can understand, but others don't.

Goodluck!